# onload not working after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, advanced-custom-fields

So basically I have a an API call to OS Maps(UK map builder). As per their documentation I get it working and it displays perfectly, but its an `onload` event and I'm using ACF(advance custom fields) in WordPress to display a map based on the map name used in the custom field.

The problem is the map loads when page loads, but the after my Ajax call when the custom map name is equal to `amlwch` it doesn't load.

This happens because its an `onload` event and the Ajax obviously doesn't do a page reload, so I just don't know how to get a way around this.

So how to get function working if Ajax call happens?

**To put it short:**

Ajax does not load page, so body onload won't be called after ajax call, what other option do I have to get it working?

**php:**

(check if custom field name, and then display function based on the name)

```
<!-- bodafon -->           
<?php if( get_post_meta($postId,'route_map_name', true) == 'bodafon' ): ?>
<body onload="initmapbuilder()">
<div id="maproute" style=" width:100%; height:440px;"></div>
</body>
<!-- amlwch -->
<?php elseif( get_post_meta($postId,'route_map_name', true) == 'amlwch' ): ?>
<body onload="initmapbuilder1()">
<div id="maproute1" style=" width:100%; height:440px;"></div>
</body>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**JS:**

(AJAX, keep in mind it works and displays all data around this map its just the `onload` not working)

```
/*Maps section ajax call*/    
$(function(){
    $('#routes').on('change', function(){



        var that = $(this);
        var post_id = that.attr('value');
       // console.log(post_id);
        $.ajax({
            url:'../../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // admin-ajax.php will handle the request
            type:'post',
            data: {
                // this is the action hook to call the handler "MyAjaxFunction"
                action: 'post_maps_items',
                // pass some data to post variblr to use in php/wordpress (optional)
                id: post_id, // you can retrieve this using $_POST['id'];
            },
            timeout : 10000,
            success:function(data){
                // returned data by wordpress
                //console.log('Success');
               // $('#load_map').html(data);
                $('#title').html(data).hide().fadeIn("slow").addClass('flex');
            }
        });

          $.ajax({
            url:'../../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // admin-ajax.php will handle the request
            type:'post',
            data: {
                // this is the action hook to call the handler "MyAjaxFunction"
                action: 'post_maps_items_info',
                // pass some data to post variblr to use in php/wordpress (optional)
                id: post_id, // you can retrieve this using $_POST['id'];
            },
            timeout : 10000,
            success:function(data){
                // returned data by wordpress
                //console.log('Success');
                $('#load_map').html(data);

               // $('#title').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why not just call `initmapbuilder1()` after ajax success

Comment: @emineminems thanks for response, well its based on what the custom field name is there is allot more than just this 2 , this is just as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So got this working using jquery method `ajaxComplete` , works:

So i removed the inline `onload` events.

**PHP**:

```
<!-- bodafon -->           
<?php if( get_post_meta($postId,'route_map_name', true) == 'bodafon' ): ?>
<body>
<div id="maproute" style=" width:100%; height:440px;"></div>
</body>
<!-- amlwch -->
<?php elseif( get_post_meta($postId,'route_map_name', true) == 'amlwch' ): ?>
<body>
<div id="maproute1" style=" width:100%; height:440px;"></div>
</body>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After each ajax call i call the functions which wil only show based on custom field name as can see above , as each function is based in  an unique `ID`.

Also i call my first function in `.ready` event so that it loads before any AJAC call happens.

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("#maproute").length != 0) {
    initmapbuilder();   
  }
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  initmapbuilder();  
  initmapbuilder1();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#load_map').html(data);
```

This will remove all events inside "#load_map". Check if events are restored after this

Comment: hi @ShishirArora but im using that within the Ajax call it works, its the `onload` event not happening after the AJAX thats not working , even tho it brings back the correct data , its just that after the AJAX call the page doesnt load, so the function in above **php** is not working then.

Comment: ajax does not load page, so body onload wont be called after ajax call